# Incorrect order of references

Tags: bibliographies, sorting

I am preparing a draft in two column format, but unfortunately I have a major problem:  I have written my references in a separately text file and called that `art-bib`, also I have used of

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

     \include{art-bib}

\end{thebibliography}
```

for summons that.

Although it calls references, but in such an arrangement on which had written reference file and not the order of calling them. For example:

```
The first sentence~\cite{ref5} and after that the second sentence~\cite{ref10} and so on..
```

It writes to me as:

```
The first sentence [5] and after that the second sentence [10] and so on..
```

I expect I have :

```
The first sentence [1] and after that the second sentence [2] and so on..
```

Comment: Is the file you are inputing a bibtex file or does it contain bibitems? Please give a MWE.

Comment: Sorting/numbering is what `bibtex` or `biblatex` is made for, amongst other features of course. I don't see the point in doing this by hand with `\bibitem` stuff

Comment: My file is art-bib.txt and in that I have written as:  \bibitem{trau97} M. Trau, D. A. Saville, and I. A. Aksay, Langmuir {\bf 13}, 6375 (1997).

Comment: OK: you are not using bibtex or biblatex. Now the MWE shoing the problem?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I don't understand what is MWE? How can I use bibtex or biblatex correctly?

Comment: @InzoBabaria: See here please: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: You should *not* use `\include` in that case, but `\input`.

Comment: If you write the bibliography by hand, then it just comes in the order you write it and to change the order you need to change the order of teh bibitems, but it is usually better _not_ to write that list by hand and let bibtex generate it

Comment: I so much searched and have tried to use of bibtex, but just I have been confused! there is no straightforward way to use bibtex for a sample draft! All webs have so many not needed explanations which just confused users!

Comment: @InzoBabaria, for an one-off job, BibTeX (or similar) is overkill. If you will be using LaTeX even occasionally, you'll be extremely thankful for having a database of references from which to pick and choose. Take a peek at e.g. [it's official site](http://www.bibtex.org)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you compile the following example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{ugly} and \cite{good} followed by \cite{bad}

\begin{thebibliography}{3}

\bibitem{good} C. Eastwood, \emph{A good paper}, Journal \textbf{42} (2015), pp.~1--2.

\bibitem{bad} L. Van Cleef, \emph{A bad paper}, Journal \textbf{42} (2015), pp.~3--4.

\bibitem{ugly} E. Wallach, \emph{An ugly paper}, Journal \textbf{42} (2015), pp.~5--6.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

LaTeX produces

[image]

Using `\input{art-bib}`, where `art-bib.tex` contains the bibliographic data, is the same. Don't call `\include` for this in any case: it is wrong.

LaTeX does no sorting whatsoever. You *can* do this without using BibTeX, provided you add some macros and type in the bibliographic data in a different way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\citation}[1]{%
  \g@addto@macro{\citation@list}{,#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\citation@list}{} % initialize
\newcommand{\sortbibitem}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{bibitem@#1}{%
    \bibitem{#1} #2
  }%
}
\newcommand{\sort@bibitems}{%
  \@for\next:=\citation@list\do{%
    \@nameuse{bibitem@\next}%
    \global\@namedef{bibitem@\next}{}%
  }%
}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\endthebibliography\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\sort@bibitems\endthebibliography
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{ugly} and \cite{good} followed by \cite{bad}

Again \cite{good}

\begin{thebibliography}{3}

\sortbibitem{good}{C. Eastwood, \emph{A good paper}, Journal \textbf{42} (2015), pp.~1--2.}

\sortbibitem{bad}{L. Van Cleef, \emph{A bad paper}, Journal \textbf{42} (2015), pp.~3--4.}

\sortbibitem{ugly}{E. Wallach, \emph{An ugly paper}, Journal \textbf{42} (2015), pp.~5--6.}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is not provided by the LaTeX kernel, because BibTeX is much better at it. Prepare a file `art-bib.bib` containing

```
@article{good,
  author={Eastwood, C.},
  title={A good paper},
  journal={Journal},
  volume={42},
  year=2015,
  pages={1-2},
}
@article{bad,
  author={Van Cleef, L.},
  title={A bad paper},
  journal={Journal},
  volume={42},
  year=2015,
  pages={3-4},
}
@article{ugly,
  author={Wallach, E.},
  title={An ugly paper},
  journal=Journal},
  volume={42},
  year=2015,
  pages={5-6},
}
```

Then your document can be

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{ugly} and \cite{good} followed by \cite{bad}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{art-bib}

\end{document}
```

Let's say your main file is named `myarticle.tex`. Upon compilation with `pdflatex myarticle`, you run `bibtex myarticle` and again `pdflatex` (twice if the terminal tells you to).

The output will be essentially the same. The big advantage is that the data in `art-bib.bib` is *reusable* in several different formats, as specified by the bibliography style you select with the `\bibliographystyle` command.

Note that the above type of sorting is only possible with the order of citation. Alphabetical sorting by author can only be obtained with BibTeX or its successors `biblatex`/Biber.